# Docker-compose re-write file for version 2 to version 1

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have an elk docker-compose file that I think cannot run on my server because the docker-compose version is too old...

```
$ docker-compose -version
docker-compose version 1.6.2, build 4d72027
```

And here is my docker-compose file...

```
version: '2'
services:
    elasticsearch:
      image: elasticsearch:5
      command: elasticsearch
      environment:
        # This helps ES out with memory usage
        - ES_JAVA_OPTS=-Xmx1g -Xms1g
      volumes:
        # Persist elasticsearch data to a volume
        - elasticsearch:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data
        # Extra ES configuration options
        - ./es/elasticsearch.yml:/usr/share/elasticsearch/config/elasticsearch.yml
      ports:
        - "9200:9200"
        - "9300:9300"

    logstash:
      image: logstash:5
      command: logstash -w 4 -f /etc/logstash/conf.d/logstash.conf
      environment:
        # This helps Logstash out if it gets too busy
        - LS_HEAP_SIZE=2048m
      volumes:
        # volume mount the logstash config
        - ./logstash/logstash.conf:/etc/logstash/conf.d/logstash.conf
        - /Users/rriviere/workspace/parks-dpe/activities-api-v1/app-logs/:/tmp/app-logs
      ports:
        # GELF port for Docker logs
        - "12201:12201/udp"
        # UDP port for syslogs
        - "5000:5000/udp"
        # Default TCP port
        - "5001:5001"
      links:
        - elasticsearch

    kibana:
      image: kibana:5
      environment:
        # Point Kibana to the elasticsearch container
        - ELASTICSEARCH_URL=http://elasticsearch:9200
      ports:
        - "5601:5601"
      links:
        - elasticsearch

    kopf:
      image: rancher/kopf:v0.4.0
      ports:
        - "8080:80"
      environment:
        KOPF_ES_SERVERS: "elasticsearch:9200"
      links:
        - elasticsearch

volumes:
  elasticsearch:
```

Whilst I'm not looking for an exact answer here can someone help me with what is required to create myself a docker compose v1 file that would do the same things.

thanks

Comment: I think better to upgrade your docker-compose

Comment: Does upgrading docker compose affect docker? For example are there dependencies between the two?

Answer (score 0):

you better check the docs for more details but just looking at your file, I think if you remove following lines then you are good to go:

```
version: '2'
services:
```

version 2 has some additional features which I dont see in your case, so you are pretty compatible with v1.